# Is it possible to do oracle import util as non-dba user?

Tags: oracle, importerror, imp, oracle-dump

When I try to import an oracle dump. Following the error displayed,

*Export file created by EXPORT:V10.02.01 via direct path*

*IMP-00013: only a DBA can import a file exported by another DBA*

*IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully*

I just wondering If the non-dba user exports a dump file. Can non-dba user import the dump file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes , non-dba user can import/export files from his/her schema without any problem. But if it wants to import/export files to/from other schema it must have been granted IMP_FULL_DATABASE/EXP_FULL_DATABASE roles .

BUT, here I can see that you are trying to import dump file, which was exported by **direct path**. In this situation just DBA can import directly exported file.

You can temporarily grant DBA role to this user , import file and then revoke this privilege.

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> grant IMP_FULL_DATABASE to test;
```

*I hope it was helpfull for you :)*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works fine to export and import under a non-DBA user.  You'll still need a privileged login to create the destination user if it doesn't already exist.